# I want to upgrade my power in y mobile home

Tags: electrical

I have a mobile home wich is 583 sq ft
I want to upgrade the power service for the meter
I install already 100amps breaker after the meter
I go to run #2 aluminum wire from there to the electrical box inside the house [25 ft far aprox]
Once I do all this do I can have any risk?
Thanks…

Comment: Upgrading your power service is up to the power company if you can.  Putting a bigger breaker in, means nothing if the power company says no.  If the power company is supplying you with a 100 amp service, then you should be okay if you follow the electrical code for where you live.

Comment: Your panel must be rated for a larger breaker, double check that.

Comment: There is always risk in working with electricity - far more risk if you don't understand what you are doing, or fail to follow correct procedures when doing work. Both electrocution and electrical fires kill numerous people. It's not hard to do right, but it's easy to do wrong, as well.

Comment: Does the electrical code where you live even allow you to make this modification, or does it require the services of a licensed electrician?